# Which TransactionManger is to use to rollback an event send to an channel

Tags: spring, messaging, spring-integration, spring-transactions

If I want to use Spring Intergration and if I want to do a rollback of a message, that I have sent before, which kind of TransactionManger is to use. I did not want to use jms active-mq or such things, only sending an event to a queue:

```
class DatingServiceImpl  {

    @Autowired
    final RendezvousChannel rendezvousChannel

    @Autowired
    final GirlsRepository girlsRepository

    @Transactional()
    public final date(final String name ) {

        rendezvousChannel.send(String.format("Hello %s", name ), 100);

        if( girlsRepository.forName(name).hotScore < 8 ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No I put it over");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a JmsTransactionManager provided by:

```
org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager.
```

The API can be seen [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/JmsTransactionManager.html).

Comment: thanks. I've tried it If I add  the transactionManager I need a JMSConnectionFactory.  An in my case it is to mutch (both persistence and JMS) . I did not realy need  it. I can check conditions before sending the message and then not send it. It is only a trigger for Datareplication. I mean it would be mutch more polite to check the score before  asking ... It was only the first trial with spring integation.  For otherr scenarios  I will use persitent queues or jms

Answer (score 0):

> ...I did not want to use jms active-mq or such things...

There is no such transaction manager - the framework itself is not transactional; to get transactions, the channel has to be backed by some transactional resource such as JMS or JDBC.